# Could not submit my theme on wp directory for warnings of SMOF base64decode

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have designed a theme by wordpress directory. I ave used SMOF (slightly modified options framework) for theme options. I could not submit the theme on wordpress. There was two warnings:

```
WARNING:Found base64_encode in the file class.options_machine.php. base64_encode() is not allowed.

Line 546: $output .= '<textarea id='export_data' rows='8'>'.base64_encode(serialize($smof_data)) /* 100% safe - ignore theme check nag
```

And

```
WARNING: Found base64_decode in the file functions.interface.php. base64_decode() is not allowed.
Line 228: $smof_data = unserialize(base64_decode($smof_data)); //100% safe - ignore theme check nag
```

I found it from SMOF files.
Now how can I solve this or what should I have to do? Should I remove this code or there is another way to pass this? If I remove this code from SMOF, then is the SMOF working properly?

Comment: I believe you can not submit obfuscated code to WordPress.org Theme repository.

Comment: I am new in wordpress theme development. What is obfuscated code and how can I submit?

Answer (score 0):

Rick is correct. Wordpress.org does not allow obfuscated code.

You should include the original source code, (or manually remove the obfuscated code) and resubmit.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Review#Guidelines